# Solving an equation has restricted values for being undefined but is not applicable to all forms

Tags: algebra-precalculus

For example, in the case of this algebraic expression

$${7x^2+14x\over2x+4}$$

It is provided that $x \ne -2$, since division by 0 is not defined. It is understandable that replacing $-2$ will put forth an undefined solution. However on further simplification i.e.

$${7x^2+14x\over2x+4} = {7x(x+2)\over2(x+2)} = {7x\over2}$$

we can also include $-2$ as a solvable value for $x$. My confusion here is, if $x$ cannot be $-2$, how is it possible that it can be used in a reduced form, shouldn't it be not usable in all forms of the algebraic expression?

Comment: it has a removable discontinuity at $x=-2$

Comment: thanks @RakibulIslamPrince

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is known as a removable discontinuity. By simplifying the original function, you reached a new function with that gap removed. Note that the original function and the simplified function are NOT the same because their domains aren't the same. As another example:
$$y = \frac{x(x+2)}{x+2}; \quad y = x$$

If you simplify the first function, you reach the second function. However, they aren't the same since the second function is defined for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ whereas the first is defined for all $x \neq -2$. If you graph them, they're the exact same, except the first has a gap at $x = -2$, while the second does not. (By simplifying, you removed that gap, or discontinuity at $x = -2$.) The same applies to your example.

Comment: I'm a complete math noob here. I kind of understand your statement, thanks for that, however aren't both expressions regarded to be one and the same. Plotting a graph over these functions cast a light about your statement, however I am still unclear of how the removal is even possible considering that they both appear the same to me.

Comment: If they don't have the same domain, they aren't really the "same"! That's the point. Your second function is equivalent to your first in all ways except for the fact that the second function also has $x = -2$ in its domain, and that's what makes it different. My example highlights the same point.

Comment: Oh, so mathematically speaking two expressions aren't the same if their 'domains' aren't the same. I get it now. Kudos.

Comment: Yes, exactly! (They are the same in every other way except for the difference in their domains.)

Answer (score 0):

The two expressions are equivalent for $x\neq -2$ that is

$${7x^2+14x\over2x+4} = {7x\over2}$$

but for $x=-2$ the LHS is not defined.

In that case we can assign a value to the LHS also for $x=-2$, notably if we define

$${7x^2+14x\over2x+4} = -7, \quad x=-2$$

the two expression become completely equivalent (in that case we define it a [**removable discontinuity**](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RemovableDiscontinuity.html)).

Comment: But doesn't this contradict @km101's statement of both expressions not being equivalent?

Comment: @SriramJayaraman Without any specification (first line) they are equivalent for all $x\neq -2$ but if we define ${7x^2+14x\over2x+4} = -7$  for $x=-2$ they become completely equivalent.

Comment: I get that now I guess, when we convert the expression into an equation with the desired value, both of them become equivalent. Thanks.

Comment: @SriramJayaraman Yes exactly, since for any $x\in\mathbb{R}$ they return the same value.

Answer (score 0):

I would draw a very rough sketch...
Say,you have some functions like

$f_1(x)=x^2$

$f_2(x)=\dfrac{3x}{13}$

$f_3(x)=\sqrt{x-1}$

now multiply $(x+2)$ with both the numerator and the denominator of those function .
Now they appear to be -

$f_1(x)=\dfrac{x^2(x+2)}{(x+2)}$

$f_2(x)=\dfrac{3x.(x+2)}{13(x+2)}$

$f_3(x)=\dfrac{\sqrt{x-1}.(x+2)}{13(x+2)}$

Now what do you say,each of the function is not valid at $x=-2$ !!!!
does it make any sense?Clearly this $x=-2$ point has nothing to do with those functions. This is purely irrelevant .so we must have to remove them.like this,in every function at first we should look for a removable discontinuity.if it exists then we must have to remove it to get the actual domain of the function.